# nodejs developer using amd syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, commonjs

I have already read the differences between commonjs, es6, amd modularities of many articles.

This is not a question asking about the relations and differences between those above, meaning no duplication.

Currently I am using nodejs and this time studying webpack4 bundler for more good performance.

it seems that nodejs is using commonjs modularity(exports object & require function), and reactjs or client side javascript etc using es6 modularity (import, export).

So the question is that, is AMD not frequently used nowadays for nodejs developers?

Wondering about this issue because I have no experience of using amd define function since I started javascript-nodejs programming (almost one year).

Again, is AMD just included in the history of javascript modularity, not quietly used nowadays for nodejs developers? (contrast to commonjs)

If not, any examples of usage might really be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @jwkoo, this question is likely to attract opinion based answers and therefore is not a good fit for StackOverflow. I would recommend asking it on a friendlier / discussion focused site like https://www.askquestions.tech/

Comment: And as a quick comment, Angular JS uses an AMD style module system, so it's still in use. It's never (or really rarely) used on the server-side because of how CommonJS is baked-in to node as a first class module loading system

Comment: @FredStark Appreciate for your advice. so nodejs with react developer rarely does not use AMD style, right? I thought that I studied in wrong way.. if your post your answer, and I will take that. and also, I will post questions like this issue in askquestions.tech as you suggested. thanks!